# Loop though subsites and get all Property Bags - jQuery deferred issue

Tags: jquery, site-collection, site, ajax

I'm trying to loop through all subsites under a site collection, get a Property Bag per site and push all the gathered results into an array. I'm having trouble checking if all the jQuery promises have been resolved so I can process the array. Please let me know if I am missing something:

```
                var promises=[];
                var subSiteEnum = SubSites.getEnumerator();

                while (subSiteEnum.moveNext()) {

                var res = (function(){
                    var dfd = $.Deferred();
                    var Site = subSiteEnum.get_current();
                    var webTemplate = Site.get_webTemplate();       
                    var SiteContext = new SP.ClientContext(Site.get_url());
                    var allProperties = SiteContext.get_web().get_allProperties();

                    SiteContext.load(allProperties);

                    if(webTemplate != 'APP')
                    SiteContext.executeQueryAsync(
                        function() {
                            dfd.resolve(allProperties);
                        },
                        function(sender, args) {
                            dfd.fail(args);
                        }
                    );

                    return dfd.promise(); 


               })();   


                res.done( function( data ) {
                     var Prop = data.get_fieldValues()["projectSector"];
                     if (Prop != undefined) {
                        console.log('pushing: ' + Prop);
                        projectSubSites.push({
                            projectManager: Prop
                        });
                     }
                });

                res.fail( function( data ) {
                    console.log(data);
                });

                promises.push(res);

                } //end while   

                console.log(promises);
                $.when.apply($, promises).then(allDone);

                function allDone(){
                    console.log(projectSubSites);
                    console.log('processed all items');
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the stuff with promises important? If not why not just use **'Include(AllProperties)'** to include the properties and do something like this:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var webs = context.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_webs();
context.load(webs, 'Include(AllProperties)');
context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
  var enumerator = webs.getEnumerator();
  while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
    console.log(enumerator.get_current().get_allProperties().get_fieldValues());
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I can work with that solution. I can't believe I was trying to make it so complicated. It's hard being an SP noob haha.